# How to Measure Azure Function Cold Start Time

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cold-start

I've been doing research lately around Azure Function [cold start time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/02/07/understanding-serverless-cold-start/) that can occur with a consumption-based plan. I understand the concepts, but how do I actually measure the cold start time of my Azure Functions? I can't seem to find any good documentation on this.

In the Azure Portal, I see there is a "Monitor" tab for each of my functions, but the only statistic shown is "Duration (MS)" and it is unclear if this includes the start up time.

In general, are there better ways to monitor this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that there is an official metric which shows cold start time.

I've been measuring it by running a function with predictable "hot" execution time, and then measuring the total latency from a client who calls the function. The client was located in the same region as function under test.

Also, my function was returning the ID of an instance it was running on. The first response from each instance is definitely a cold start.

I hope you find my blog posts on cold starts useful:

- [Cold Starts in Numbers](https://mikhail.io/2018/04/azure-functions-cold-starts-in-numbers/)
- [Cold Starts Beyond First Request](https://mikhail.io/2018/05/azure-functions-cold-starts-beyond-first-load/)

Comment: I read both of your articles. They were extremely insightful, thank you.

Comment: Have you been using App Insights for this measurement?

Comment: I did use App Insights, but not metrics reported by Functions themselves, but the end-to-end response time measured on client-side

Comment: Very good articles, thanks  

And here seems to be the latest article on the series: https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/azure/